# Can't catch typescript error in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, try-catch, redux-toolkit

I can't catch the error. I deliberately messed up the query string to handle this case, but it still gets through. With developer tools open, the app **crashes**. I am using axios, redux-toolkit and typescript. Please tell me what should I do?

```
export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/fetchAll',
    async (_, {rejectWithValue}) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get<IUser[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/use2rs')
            return response.data
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof Error) {
                return rejectWithValue(e.message)
            }

        }
    }
)
```

But when I use such a tool, everything works well. However, I'd like to use the convenience of createAsyncThunk and rejectWithValue

```
export const fetchUsers = () => async (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(userSlice.actions.usersFetching())
        const response = await axios.get<IUser[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        dispatch(userSlice.actions.usersFetchingSuccess(response.data))
    } catch (e: any) {
        dispatch(userSlice.actions.usersFetchingError(e.message))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof Error` almost never works, since `extending` JavaScript-internal classes like `Error` can result in classes that technically do not keep the right property chain. This might differ depending on your transpilation target.

Better check something like `typeof error.message == 'string'` or write a little typeguard:

```
function hasMessage(e: any): e is {message: string} {
  return e && typeof e.message == 'string'
}

// ...

if (hasMessage(e)) return rejectWithValue(e.message)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total newbie, but where can I get the error field from the hasMessage function?

Comment: Oh sorry, typo. Should be `e.message`. Let me fix it.

Comment: I just tried this, but when the developer tool is open, it still crashes

Comment: You never mentioned any crash. Maybe add that to your question, with the full error message? This shouldn't have anything to do with crashing behaviour though

Comment: I'm sorry, I've corrected the description

Comment: Describe the crash. Does the computer fall from the table? Do you get an error message (which error message?)? Do you get a white screen? Is there text on the console? Does it just get unresponsive? It could mean anything.

Comment: When the developer tools are open, I have a page reload

Comment: And why do you think it has anything to do with this code? No error would ever make the browser reload, only a navigation event like a `history.push`.

Comment: Because if I make a request via redux-thunk as in the code below, then everything works correctly, and with CreateAsyncThunk I get an error in the source and the page is reloaded.
I have no other assumptions

Comment: So you are getting an error? Could you please finally actually share that error?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't answer then, the reason was in the Windows kernel, everything works fine on Ubuntu. Tested on 3 different computers and different OS